# Force Close again and again

Tags: android

code:

```
package com.guess.guessthefone;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaPlayer logoMusic;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        MediaPlayer logoMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.splash_sound);
        logoMusic.start();

        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){

            public void run(){


                try{
                    sleep(2000);
                Intent MenuIntent =  new Intent("com.guess.guessthefone.SPLASH");
                    startActivity(MenuIntent);



                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{


                    finish();

                }
            }

        };
        logoTimer.start();
    }




    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

My LogCat ouptput is:

```
08-24 16:40:33.558: D/dalvikvm(322): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 48K, 53% free 2551K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 74ms

08-24 16:40:36.048: W/dalvikvm(322): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

08-24 16:40:36.057: E/AndroidRuntime(322): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10

08-24 16:40:36.057: E/AndroidRuntime(322): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.guess.guessthefone.Menu }

08-24 16:40:36.057: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)

08-24 16:40:36.057: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)

08-24 16:40:36.057: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)

08-24 16:40:36.057: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)

08-24 16:40:36.057: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.guess.guessthefone.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:29)
```

Comment: What does the LogCat say?

Comment: put media player in a separate thread

Comment: Not trying to pull you down, but you should be the person who first puts some effort in solving this issue, by appropriately describing the issue, and how, when does it occur.

Comment: @AndyRes Well its cool , appreciate your comment. But i tried my best changing  everything i could. Whenver i open the application  after 2 secs ( timer) i get force close and its just my first question on stackoverflow , i am not really into it. just wanted some help so came down here.

Comment: I see. I suggest you read the FAQ page for getting the most of StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/faq
Regarding the issue, I agree with @Chirag Raval's answer below.

Comment: @AndyRes Thanks i'll certainly do that .

Answer (score 1):

Change this.

```
  Intent MenuIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this,SPLASH.class);
  startActivity(MenuIntent);
```

and declared your **SPLASH** Activity in android manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".SPLASH"/>
```

Comment: I think its your second activity name which are you trying to call ? Change SPLASH to your calling activity name

Comment: Yeah i tried that. Its still the same error. another thing is  my timer is for  2 secs but the music keeps on playing after the application goes on force close whereas it should halt after 2 secs.

Comment: where is com.guess.guessthefone.Menu Activity ?

Comment: that's my second activity name.

Comment: <activity
        android:name=".MENU"

Comment: Have you replace this code ? 
Intent MenuIntent =  new Intent("com.guess.guessthefone.SPLASH");
startActivity(MenuIntent);

Comment: Give me 5-10 mins let me work it out with your way perfectly and then get back to you. you got any gtalk or any messenger ?

Answer (score 1):

MOREOVER,The player should be prepared before playing the video. you should a touch preparedlistener

```
final MediaPlayer logoMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.splash_sound);
//set your dataSource here
logoMusic .setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    logoMusic.start();
    }
});
```